# Diode bridge working only as half recitifier

Tags: diodes

I am trying to simulate diode bridge using 12.

In the image below you can see the circuit and the simulation of the circuit.

So my question is, why does this circuit does not behave as full-wave recitifier? It is only passing a half wave, the negative one.

Thanks for the help!!!

[image: My circuit simulation]

Comment: I found the answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54965/diode-bridge-in-simulator-not-behaving-as-expected?rq=1